# What order is needed to get the highest level enchantments on Diamond Armor in Minecraft without reaching "Too Expensive!"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my Minecraft Survival world, I am attempting to get the strongest possible armor I can. Currently, I can easily create the chestplate and leggings with Protection IV, Thorns III, Mending, and Unbreaking III without maxing out the anvil uses, but I can't achieve the same with the helmet or boots. For the boots I was trying to get Protection IV, Thorns III, Feather Falling IV, Depth Strider III, Unbreaking III, Mending. For the helmet I was trying to get Protection IV, Thorns III, Aqua Infinity, Respiration III, Unbreaking III, Mending. But I can't seem to find out what order is needed to achieve this without going over the limit, and anvil mechanics go right over my head. I figured asking this at least may provide a shortcut for people who need a quick reference for what order is needed to get their overpowered armor.

In conclusion, **what order is needed to achieve max enchantments on diamond armor without going over the cap?**

Comment: @MarkGiraffe Using books is obvious. You need to use an anvil to actually get the enchantments from the books onto armor, and it still maxes it out before max enchantments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. You need to enchant books to the desired level, and you can combine Protection, Thorns, Unbreaking and Mending books together and it is safe to enchant without going over the cap. Just make sure each enchantment is separate first before combining them.

What about the extras? It's safe to add them up, as long as they are separate.

So the sequence is as follows:

- Get Protection IV, Thorns III, Unbreaking III, and Mending I as separate books.
- Combine all the separate books into one.
- Enchant each diamond armor with the enchanted combination, and:
- Add extras separately on helmet and boots.

Comment: This also works for Java Edition.